# GitBash: unable to change directory

Tags: bash, github, git-bash

I am trying to use git bash to change directories to C:\Users\Meng Luo\Documents, but even though the 'Meng Luo' subdirectory shows up when I cd to C:\Users, then ls, I cannot cd to that subdirectory.

I have tried using quotation marks and / to eliminate the space in 'Meng Luo' -- any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 ~
$ cd C:\Users\Meng Luo\Documents
bash: cd: too many arguments

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 ~
$ cd \Users\Meng Luo\Documents
bash: cd: too many arguments


Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 ~
$ cd "C:\Users\Meng Luo\Documents"
bash: cd: C:\Users\Meng Luo\Documents: No such file or directory

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 ~
$ cd 'C:\Users\Meng Luo\Documents'
bash: cd: C:\Users\Meng Luo\Documents: No such file or directory


Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c
$ ls
'$Recycle.Bin'/             eSupport/      Intel/         PerfLogs/               ProgramData/   swapfile.sys                  Windows/
 devlist.txt                Finish.log     msdia80.dll*  'Program Files'/         Python27/     'System Volume Information'/
'Documents and Settings'@   hiberfil.sys   pagefile.sys  'Program Files (x86)'/   Recovery/      Users/



Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ ls
'All Users'@   Default/  'Default User'@   desktop.ini  'Meng Luo'/   Public/

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd \'Meng Luo'
>
> ls

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd /'Meng Luo'/
bash: cd: /Meng Luo/: No such file or directory

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd /'Meng Luo'
bash: cd: /Meng Luo: No such file or directory

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd /Meng\ Luo
bash: cd: /Meng Luo: No such file or directory

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd /Desktop
bash: cd: /Desktop: No such file or directory

Meng Luo@DESKTOP-B8KRUTR MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd /desktop.ini
bash: cd: /desktop.ini: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The duplicate is approximate but hopefully should help you understand the meaning of `/` at the beginning of a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im currently not on windows so i cant verify

try

```
cd /c/Users/'Meng Luo'/Documents
```

your error above it that you include a / at the begining

the / has special meaning in this context

it is the root directory where your drives and some system folders are
you can make an `ls /` to see what folders are there.

so if you want to change to a different folder from the current folder
you omit the /

example your in /c/Users and want to switch to Meng Luo:

`cd 'Meng Luo'`